# Django 1.5 Geodjango pointfield as map in admin inline

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a model

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Venue(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_('Event') )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    geometry = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Now I am trying to show geometry field as a map in inline admin class

```
class VenueInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Venue
    extra = 1
```

But django does not show the map instead a text area.  What is the best way to show the map within inlines ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-location-field](https://github.com/codasus/django-location-field):

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from location_field.models import LocationField

class Venue(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, verbose_name=_('Event') )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    geometry = LocationField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

For more examples, take a look at the example_project [models.py](https://github.com/codasus/django-location-field/blob/master/example_project/example_project/models.py).

Comment: There is note on project page : This project is currently unusable and under heavy work

Comment: @ratata I'm currently working on some issues so this warning will be removed later today.

Comment: My Django has this functionality per default via OSM (openstreetmaps) and OpenLayer Tech, I don't know what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @caio - If we do not use an inline admin and use -- --  admin.site.register(Venue, admin.OSMGeoAdmin) ---  Everything works fine and we can mark on the map... Can't we use the same django structure and make it available for inlines ?  Why do you add extra google map js ?